# Oracle Timesten source language

Tags: oracle, timesten

Anyone knows what is the source language used for Oracle TimesTen? Is it C++ or Java? Cannot find the answer for that anywhere.

Comment: It's pretty easy: if the binaries are stored in `.jar` files it's Java. Otherwise it's something different (might be C++)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Timesten binaries writen in plain C

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle TimesTen binaries are mostly written in ANSI C with a little bit of C++.

TimesTen runs on Linux, Windows, Solaris/Sparc, Solaris/x86, AIX and HP-UX.